# Build error with "___report_rangecheckfailure" with OpenSSL libs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, openssl, sha

Using VC++ 2010

Compiling with OpenSSL libraries to make a SHA512 hash...

getting this build error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Second, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  AssemblyInfo.cpp
1>Second.cpp
1>  Second.cpp(64): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\stdio.h(371) : see declaration of 'sprintf'
1>  Generating Code...
1>  .NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cpp
1>  Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.40219.01
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>  
1>  "/OUT:C:\Users\Boss\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Second\Debug\Second.exe" /INCREMENTAL "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\VC\static\ssleay32MD.lib" "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\VC\static\libeay32MD.lib" kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /ASSEMBLYRESOURCE:Debug\Second.Form1.resources /MANIFEST "/ManifestFile:Debug\Second.exe.intermediate.manifest" "/MANIFESTUAC:level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG "/PDB:C:\Users\Boss\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Second\Debug\Second.pdb" /ASSEMBLYDEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /TLBID:1 "/ENTRY:main" /DYNAMICBASE /FIXED:NO /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 Debug\app.res 
1>  Debug\AssemblyInfo.obj 
1>  Debug\Second.obj 
1>  Debug\stdafx.obj 
1>  "Debug\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.obj" 
1>libeay32MD.lib(obj_dat.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___report_rangecheckfailure referenced in function _OBJ_create_objects
1>libeay32MD.lib(b_print.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___report_rangecheckfailure
1>C:\Users\Boss\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Second\Debug\Second.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Tried disabling buffer overrun security check, same error..

Any thoughts?  Tried all day with Crypto++, to no avail, OpenSSL was much easier, just hung up on this one error...

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you are trying to link to OpenSSL libraries that were built with a later version of the compiler.

Function ___report_rangecheckfailure was introduced in more recent versions of Visual Studio (see http://blogs.microsoft.com/cybertrust/2012/01/26/enhancements-to-gs-in-visual-studio-11/ for details).

So the linker is looking in the VS2010 libraries to find a function that didn't exist until later.

The maintainer of at least one of the pre-built OpenSSL libraries for Windows has recently switched from using an earlier version of Visual Studio, which may be the trigger for your problems.

One solution is to build your own OpenSSL Windows binaries with VS2010 (See http://developer.covenanteyes.com/building-openssl-for-visual-studio/ for example).